# jQuery UI tabs preventing moving to another page in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a weird issue with an image rotator I wrote using jQuery UI Tabs. The rotator works fine, however, if the user tries to move to another page either by clicking a link, using the URL toolbar, or selecting a bookmark, and the rotator moves to the next image before the next page is loaded, that redirection is canceled and the user is "stuck" on the page with the rotator.

Has anyone heard of this issue, and better yet, how to resolve it?

I'm using:

jquery.1.7.min.js
jquery-ui.1.8.21.min.js

Source code below:

```
/*Our main js library*/
var spLib = {
rotator:
{
    ROTATION_DELAY: 9000,
    init: function () {
        this.beginRotator();

        //Stretch control links to appropriate width based on the number of them
        var links = $('#rotatorLinks a[href^=#tabs-]');
        var controlLinkCount = links.length;
        //Divide the 600px of reserved space into allotments for the control links
        var linkWidth = 600 / controlLinkCount;
        //Apply width
        links.each(function () {
            $(this).css('width', linkWidth + 'px');
        });

        var $this = this;
        //When pause button is clicked, determine current pause state and either unpause rotation, or pause it
        $('.pauseButton').click(
            function () {
                if ($('.pauseButton').data('pauseState') === 'unpaused') {
                    $("#tabs").tabs("rotate", 0, false);
                    //Flip pause button to play button
                    $('.pauseButton').css('background-image', 'url(/_layouts/images/RotatorWebPart/play.png)');
                    $('.pauseButton').data('pauseState', 'paused')
                } else {
                    $this.beginRotator();
                    $this.moveToNext();
                }
                return false;
            });
    },
    beginRotator: function () {
        var $this = this;
        $('#tabs').tabs({
            fx:
            {
                opacity: "toggle"
            }
        }).tabs("rotate", $this.ROTATION_DELAY, false);
        $('#tabs img').css('left', '0');
        $('.pauseButton').css('background-image', 'url(/_layouts/images/RotatorWebPart/pause.png)');
        $('.pauseButton').data('pauseState', 'unpaused');
    },
    moveToNext: function () {
        //Get currently selected control link
        var selected = $('#tabs .ui-tabs-selected');
        //Get number of control links
        var links = $('#rotatorLinks li');

        var selectedIndex = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if ($(links[i]).hasClass('ui-tabs-selected')) {
                if (i === links.length - 1) {
                    selectedIndex = 0
                }
                else {
                    selectedIndex = i;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', selectedIndex);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're sure the browser doesn't just crash

Comment: `rotate` did get deprecated and removed from tabs API in more recent versions...possibly a related bug , would check bug tracker and changelogs

Comment: Dev tools was brought up, Start Debugging clicked, and no error was thrown when the user was prevented from moving to another page.